# How to have 2 colors in TD background with CSS

Tags: css

I have an event calendar that made use of CSS to paint the background red, to hilight holidays:

```
.holiday {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #da1030;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height:20px;
        width:20px;
}
```

For special events, I used purple as the background:

```
.sp_event {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: purple;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height:20px;
        width:20px;
}
```

Things work okay:
This to hilight holiday on 1st of this month
     1

This to indicate special event that falls on the 5th of this month
     5

BUT there are times that my special event falls on a holiday. So in this case, I want to have the TD background to be painted in red and purple, dividing the TD in 2 equal halves. Could you guys show me how this can be done with CSS? TIA.

Comment: Can you show us some HTML

Comment: This to hilight holiday on 1st of this month
<td class="holiday">1</a>

...
...

This to indicate special event that falls on the 5th of this month
<td class="sp_event">5</a>

Comment: Edit that into your question

Answer (score 3):

#### [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MEAF3/)

One solution people use is to use a [gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/linear-gradient):

```
background: #a423b2; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #a423b2 0%, #bf24b4 49%, #da1030 50%, #da1030 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#a423b2), color-stop(49%,#bf24b4), color-stop(50%,#da1030), color-stop(100%,#da1030)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #a423b2 0%,#bf24b4 49%,#da1030 50%,#da1030 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #a423b2 0%,#bf24b4 49%,#da1030 50%,#da1030 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #a423b2 0%,#bf24b4 49%,#da1030 50%,#da1030 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #a423b2 0%,#bf24b4 49%,#da1030 50%,#da1030 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a423b2', endColorstr='#da1030',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

I created this using [this tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). It is cross-browser complaint (IE6 up) and requires you to make no structural changes to your HTML at all.

Comment: @RamlangPorigi check the fiddle

Comment: @RamlangPorigi Here is the fiddle working with this solution if this helps you http://jsfiddle.net/H6tuz/

Comment: Its IE8 and up, Although IE6 may support your gradient, It doesnt support .class1.class2 css selectors

Answer (score 3):

You could accomplish this with a pseudoelement in the `td` that takes up half of the width and is positioned on the right to get the full width/height.

```
.holiday.sp_event:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rX7gd/

Comment: +1 Very creative idea! I never thought about using :after like that. _I_ would still probably use a gradient in production but this is an interesting approach to tackle this problem. Browser support seems pretty decent too (IE9, Chrome and FF all support)

Comment: How do I use that code? I dont seem to get any color in my TD

    <table width=100% class=year>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:4px height:4px" class=holiday.sp_event></td>
        <td style="width:4px height:4px"></td>
        <td align=left>Public Holiday</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

Comment: @RamlangPorigi The `.holiday.sp_event` syntax means "both classes at once."  Change `class=holiday.sp_event` to `class="holiday sp_event"`

Comment: Thx. Changed that. But I still get only a red box. Do I need to add anything else  :(    ?

Comment: @RamlangPorigi can you put all of your code on jsfiddle.net so I can take a look?  Or do you have a live website?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Hey sorry. First time with fiddle.net.

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/ramlangporigi/WydBH/

Comment: @RamlangPorigi you need `position: relative` on the `<td>`s.  I had to update it a bit to handle the text, so look carefully (also added `:before`): http://jsfiddle.net/WydBH/1/

Comment: @ExplosionPills thx for the update. Noticed that I have the box that contained the number 1 in red and the number 5 in purple.

What I want is the box that will contain the number 6 to be divided into 2 rectangles, the top portion, red in color and the bottom part purple in color.

Why are we getting that HUGE red and purple boxes. Please advise.

Comment: @RamlangPorigi did you click on my last link?

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes I did. Even refreshing the page won't help. I am using FF version 20.0.1  . BUT using Chrome, everything work perfectly. Any idea ?

Comment: @RamlangPorigi for FFX you could try to put the background on an element inside of the `<td>` instead of the `<td>` itself; I'm nots ure if there's another way